# In ngFor of li, ngclass is applied to all the row of li tag I want to apply one specific row

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Actually i am new bee to angular, In this code i want to ngclass is apply to one special row is clicked and ngclass is apply to clicked row if condition is true not All rows of all question please someone help thanks in advance
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgw8tn)

Comment: your question is not clear, many unknowns are there. What exactly you want to achieve, what have you tried and where it's failing you? Mention all that clearly in the post, also please go through this to understand how to ask effectively - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Will you please share your code so only we can help clarify, in your case, we can handle ngclass by using the unique value in the id, so please share your code for the clear explanation

Comment: @Hemendra I woulda agree with you but he provided a demo where you can actually understand what he means, don't just auto comment with pre fabricated comments while on triage

Comment: `[ngClass]="[isSelected&&o.Answer ? optionStyle : '']`  something similar might help partially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went through your StackBlitz, refined your code a bit. No need for the method inside the component file. All you need to update is your HTML.

However, the only issue with this is that this solution only allows selecting one li row irrespective of questionId.

**component.ts**

```
   public selectedIndex: any;
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="table table-hover table-sm">
      <button class="btn-primary" (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
  <ul *ngFor="let q of Questions">
    <li colspan="4">{{q.question}}</li>
    <li *ngFor="let o of q.options; let i = index" (click)="selectedIndex = (i+q.QuestionId)">
      <ul>
        <div>
          <li [ngClass]="{correctAnswer: o.Answer && selectedIndex===(i+q.QuestionId),
              wrongAnswer: !o.Answer && selectedIndex===(i+q.QuestionId)}">
            <strong>{{o.Id}}</strong>  {{o.Name}}
         </li>
        </div>
      </ul>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks a lot this is what i wanted. one question is related to your solution . how to apply ngclass to correct option row as well as wrong option row if wrong option row clicked first????

Comment: in my actual code correctAnswer  condition is Always true code using https://ibb.co/LpLtNRq and my firebase database look like https://ibb.co/JB0PMzc please tell me why correct Ans class is always true???

Comment: @TechieGram, the reason is your 'Ans' property is a string instead of a boolean. Thus it always returns true as it has the value 'true' and 'false' instead of true/false.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that you are changing a variable that is being used for every row of your li element , what you should do is apply the css only to the selected row and you can obtain this result by adding a property to your options object to check whether it has been selected or not and apply that css accordingly like so :

```
setClickedRow(event:any, option:any){
   option.Selected = !option.Selected;
}

Questions = [{
    question : "Find even no",
    QuestionId:"1",
    options : [
      {   Name : "A. 44", Answer : true, Selected:false},
      {   Name : "B. 45", Answer : false, Selected:false},
      {   Name : "C. 93", Answer : false, Selected:false},
      {   Name : "D. 77", Answer : false, Selected:false},
    ]
},
{
    question : "find uniqe ratio",
    QuestionId:"2",
    options : [
      {   Name: "A. 1:5", Answer: false, Selected:false},
      {   Name: "B. 1:5", Answer: false, Selected:false },
      {   Name: "C. 1:5", Answer: false, Selected:false},
      {   Name: "D. 1:5", Answer: true, Selected:false}
    ]
}]
```

And now that you have the variable to validate that the user selected that option or not you can apply the ng class with a condition to validate if matches the correct answer or not

```
<div class="table table-hover table-sm">
      <button class="btn-primary" (click)="onSave()">Save</button>
  <ul *ngFor="let q of Questions">
    <li colspan="4">{{q.question}}</li>
    <li *ngFor="let o of q.options; let i = index" (click)="setClickedRow($event,o)">
      <ul>
        <div><li  [ngClass]="{'correctAnswer': o.Selected && o.Answer, 'wrongAnswer': o.Selected && !o.Answer}"><strong>{{o.Id}}</strong>  {{o.Name}}</li></div>
      </ul>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```